# Custom Search API get broken image link

Tags: python, image, google-custom-search

I search images with custom search. I got some broken image links in response.

Like:

```
{
    u'kind': u'customsearch#result',
    u'title': u'Quality Sports Wallpapers, Sport', 
    u'displayLink': u'feelgrafix.com',
    u'htmlTitle': u'Quality <b>Sports</b> Wallpapers, <b>Sport</b>',
    u'snippet': u'We found 20 Images in \xabSports\xbb ...',
    u'htmlSnippet': u'We found 20 Images in \xab<b>Sports</b>\xbb ...', 
    u'link': u'http://feelgrafix.com/data/sports/sports-1.jpg',
    u'mime': u'image/jpeg', 
    u'image': {
        u'thumbnailWidth': 150,
        u'byteSize': 615337,
        u'height': 1075,
        u'width': 1768, 
        u'contextLink': u'http://feelgrafix.com/group/sports.html',
        u'thumbnailLink': u'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRP5hPZFmKRSooaRzGqptPjUW8NSf6DNsyK7zECMQuEYN2F-lt1-P-1RAQs',
        u'thumbnailHeight': 91
    }
}
```

The link is broken. How can I filter the broken image links with custom search restful API?

Comment: *What* custom search? Show us your code

Comment: define "broken", you could run an http request to the url and check the content type and response code.

Comment: I use google custom search api to search images. But in response I got some broken image links. Can I filter the broken image links with google custom search api? What params I need to set when request custom search api?

Comment: “run an http request to the url and check the content type and response code” It's too time consuming.

Comment: @AndyXuan: have you got any solutions?